# Random variables with zero mean always equal zero. But do random variables with infinite mean never equal zero?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have a random variable $X \in \mathbb{N}$, with arbitrarily large mean, is it trivial that $P(X=0)=0$?

I am able to prove that when its mean is zero, it takes the value zero with probability one, using e.g. the Markov inequality, but not the other way around.

I can provide exact expressions for its moments as a function of some parameter $n$, but in the limit $n \to \infty$, these moments all diverge.

As such, the variance is infinite, so it typically varies "infinitely" from its infinite mean. But can it vary all the way to $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $X \in \mathbb N$, I am assuming you mean $X$ is a discrete random variable with support among the natural numbers.

No, it is not necessary for $P(X = 0)$ even if $X$ has infinite mean. Here is a counterexample: Define the probability mass function $p$ of $X$ as:
$$
p(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}, &\text{ if } x = 0 \\
\frac{3}{\pi^2 x^2}, &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb Z_+
\end{cases}
$$ and $0$ everywhere else of course. Obviously $P(X = 0) = p(0) = 1/2 \neq 0$ by definition. But is it a valid pmf? Yes:
$$
\sum_{x = 0}^\infty p(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{\pi^2} \sum_{x = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{\pi^2} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1
$$ And, its mean is infinite:
$$
E[X] = \sum_{x = 0}^\infty xp(x) = \frac{3}{\pi^2} \sum_{x = 1}^\infty x \cdot \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{3}{\pi^2} \sum_{x = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{x} = \infty
$$ because the harmonic series diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Ok, so in general it is possible. But are there some conditions on the variable which do imply this $P(X>0)=1$ idea, when the mean is infinite? Is there just outright no information about this $P(X>0)$ available, in terms of the moments, when the moments are infinite, even on some restricted set of random variables?

Comment: @apkg In terms of moments, not that I can think of. In fact, observe that in my counterexample, all the moments are infinite too.

Comment: What if the probabilities are increasing as I approach the mean? Here, you have decreasing probabilities. In many practical situations, an infinite mean would imply P(X=0) is one of the smallest probabilities, not one of the largest. But I am not sure what to call this sort of distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by approaching the mean if the mean is infinite? Do you mean $P(X = n)$ is eventually increasing as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: For example, I have $P(X=c)<P(X=c+1)$ for all c.

Comment: @apkg That (strictly) increasing property is impossible. Notice that for any random variable $X$ with $\mathbb N$ as its support, $\sum_{c = 0}^\infty P(X = c) = 1$ as the probabilities must obviously sum to $1$. But that means, by a theorem from elementary calculus (called the divergence test, you can look it up), $P(X = c) \to 0$ as $c \to \infty$.

Comment: I am counting something in a large graph. It is the number of paths between two points. As the graph becomes large, the count goes to infinity. The individual point probabilities all go to zero, as the mean is going to infinity, otherwise, as you say, we wouldn't have a distribution (the sum of the probabilities would be greater than one). So, then does P(X=0) go to zero? Is this then not the condition?

Comment: @apkg You should post that as a new question including the graph you are using. Without the graph and the details of your calculations, we can't really say anything.

Comment: Ok, so basically there is nothing true in general like the Markov inequality in this case. We simply are left with the exact setting, in this case a random graph G(n,p), and the number of paths between two random vertices. Then, one can prove something directly about P(X>0) in that case, requiring detail form the exact setting.

Comment: @apkg Yes, there is no such general principle I am aware of that forces $P(X = 0) = 0$. In particular settings as might be your case, it can of course be true.